# How do I use variadic functions to pass arguments in a wrapper?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

When binding a key to a specific action in my application I have to use this very long line of code:

```
_maps[size_t(Context::MapType::key)]->at(GLFW_KEY_S) = std::make_unique<InputType::State>(std::move(std::make_unique<Print>("Key held: S Context: Second")));
```

I created a wrapper function for this using templates that looks like this:

```
template<class inputtype, class cmd>
void map_key(int key)
{
    _maps[size_t(Context::MapType::key)]->at(key) = std::make_unique<inputtype>(std::move(std::make_unique<cmd>("Print")));
}
```

This function works fine and is called like this, achieving (almost) the same result as the very long line above:

```
map_key<InputType::State, Print>(GLFW_KEY_S);
```

That is a lot shorter and looks really nice, however I cannot pass commands to inner pointer, in the example of type `Print`, in this way.

I read up a bit on variadic functions which seems to be the solution to this, but I couldn't make it work. my attempt was this:

```
template<class inputtype, class cmd, typename ...Args>
void map_key(int key, Args... args)
{
    _maps[size_t(Context::MapType::key)]->at(key) = std::make_unique<inputtype>(std::move(std::make_unique<cmd>(std::forward<Args>(args))));
}
```

Here I added the `typename ...Args` to the template and matching parameter. I passed it on to `std::make_unique<>` using `std::forward<Args>(args)`, but the compiler says that `args` is undefined, and that no instance of `std::make_unique<>` matches the argument list `<error_type>`.

How do I pass on the arguments in a correct manner?

Comment: when you have a variadic param pack you need to use `...` to expand it. e.g. `std::forward<Args>(args)...`

Comment: @CruzJean thank you, IntelliSense doesn't like your solution, and complains that the ellipsis shouldn't be there, but the code runs perfectly.

Comment: In addition to that, get rid of the `std::move` and the second `std::make_unique`.

Comment: @ViktorAxén What IDE are you using? It might be set to an old version that didn't have param packs. There should be an option somewhere to change that to a newer standard.

Comment: @ViktorAxén Also, btw `std::forward` is meant for handling forwarding references, so you should change the params to `Args &&...args`. otherwise you're taking by value and forwarding exclusively by rvalue ref

Comment: @0x499602D2 The second std::make_unique and the std::move is because the constructor of the first std::make_unique expects an unique_ptr as argument.

Comment: @CruzJean I'm using VS19. IntelliSense seems to agree now though, just had to think for a while I guess.

Comment: What is `InputType::State`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 InputType::State is an invoker type class. It holds a given command, which is the one created by the second std::make_unique. Each frame the Contextmanager activates the bound invokers, if the invoker is activated, its command is called. InputType::State means that, once activated, it will execute its command until deactivated. After being bound to a key, it will activate upon key press and deactivate upon key release. The naming "InputType" might need some more thought, but it works for now